# Configure Web.xml for CORS in Jersey REST API

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I've created rest web service and want to enable for CORS.
I have added below code to my API's code

```
package RestClient;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

public class CORSResponseFilter
implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {

        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");        
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");          
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia");
    }



}
```

And for accessbility I need to setup above class in web.xml file. So here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>GenerateToken</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>RestClient</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>RestClient.CORSResponseFilter</param-value>
</init-param>       
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>GenerateToken</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/Test/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

I just want to know, Did I configure correct my web.xml file for CORS ? In my local its working but before I deploy it for every one just want to make sure is it correct or not.

Can anyone please advice on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need this (and it's not even correct)

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>RestClient.CORSResponseFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Just add `@Provider` on top of you filter class. The following will scan the `RestClient` package for all your `@Path` and `@Provider` classes and register them for you.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>RestClient</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Can you please clear my one doubt ? I want to know, How the request first will reach to CORSResponseFilter class for allowing cross platform access, and then to my api's code class Token...? I mean who takes them to classes one by one (Priority wise). Because in web.xml only package name is written and that can contain multiple classes. Like in my case its two one for API's code and second mentioned in question ..! (Please bother if my question doesnt makes any sense)

Comment: The browser will make an OPTIONS request to server and it will not go through the resource. It will go straight to the filter. This is the _preflight_ request before the real request. When the browser gets the headers, it will send the real request which will reach your resource. After the resource, the filter is hit one more time

Comment: Okay..In preflight request it goes to filter. In my case its CORSResponseFilter, then how that request get to know it needs to sit as a parameter in filter method. Second, after sitting as a parameter in filter method, there is not return type(Void). So how and who sends the response back to the client(Caller) ?

Comment: Jersey calls the filter method and passes the contexts

Comment: And sending response of pref light request back to client...?